# Non-Redundant Hibernate List-Mapping (OneToMany)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

In a database there are "pastries". A pastry has zero, one, or many allergens.

Hence I'm using a list in Pastry with @OneToMany relation. Now, with this way of managing the relations, we get redundant entries, as for each pastry a new entry with the same allergen is created:

[image: Image 1]

Our current solution looks like this:

A mapping-table in between those two database tables.

[image]

How can I achieve a non-redundant solution with direct references to the allergen elements from a list in the Pastry class? I googled a lot but sadly couldn't find anything helpful.

Would look like this:
[image]

Regarding my comment on solution:
[image]

Comment: Forgot to add this: 
I know what the database looks like in theory, but I am not sure of how to implement this in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a called a `JoinTable`. Based on your schema definition this could work as a potential example:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Pastry")
@Table(name = "PASTRY")
public class Pastry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "PASTRY_ALLERGEN",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PASTRY_ALLERGEN_PASTRY"),
        inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PASTRY_ALLERGEN_ALLERGEN"),
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pastry_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "allergen_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Allergen> allergens = new HashSet<>();

}
```

For the `Pastry` association and:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Allergen")
@Table(name = "ALLERGEN")
public class Allergen {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}
```

For the `Allergen` association.

This mapping will in turn produce an intermediate table called `PastryAllergens` which will hold reference to the PK of the `Pastry` table and the PK of the `Allergen` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but thats basically just the second image without having to manually add it, right?

Thanks anyway, I'll just go with this method!

Comment: I do not think that what you want to do is possible, at least not with a relational database. You are working with relations, so you need a way of storing the relation.

Comment: One more thing: When I try to use an Allergen twice for different Pastries, it throws the exception "Duplicate entry '1' (allergen_id) for key '..." - any idea how to fix that? I can add multiple allergens to a pastry, but not use the allergen more than once

Comment: I put a picture of my insert statements in the original question at the bottom.
The green highlighted one still works, but the pink one where the same Allergen ID is used the second time doesn't

Comment: Can you please share the code where you perform your insertion, along with the stacktrace you are getting?

Comment: I posted the two classes and import.sql file here: https://hastebin.com/owuculisuw.java

Comment: Are you creating the tables on your own?

Comment: Also please share  the whole error you are getting.

Comment: The tables are created by code from Hibernate.
And sorry, my bad, the stacktrace is here: https://hastebin.com/agaqezeluq.sql

Comment: Try changing the `OneToMany` to `ManyToMany` so that the created primary key consists from the `pastry_id` and the `allergen_id` and not solely from `allergen_id`. Let me upgrade the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much man! You really made my day. I was stuck with this issue for hours.
Feel free to drop your Paypal please :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235977/discussion-between-mrmyth-and-akortex).